# Graphics not showing up on mac

Tags: java, macos, swing, awt

I'm working on an indie game project and am having an issue with graphics not being displayed when I move my project from my Windows computer to my macbook. I've updated both my Java version and my Eclipse but am still having this issue. Here are the main two files that handle the JFrame and Panel:

MainGameLoop

```
package hara;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainGameLoop {

public static final String gameName = "HARA v0.0";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame(gameName);
    f.setContentPane(new MainWindow());
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

and MainWindow

```
package hara;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import hara.gamestate.GameStateManager;

public class MainWindow extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener{
public static final int WIDTH = 320;
public static final int HEIGHT = 240;
public static double wSCALE = 4;
public static double hSCALE = 4;

private Thread thread;
private boolean running;
private int FPS = 60;
private long targetTime = 1000/FPS;

private BufferedImage image;
private Graphics2D g;

private GameStateManager gsm;

public MainWindow(){
    super();
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)(WIDTH * wSCALE), (int)(HEIGHT * hSCALE)));
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocus();
}

public void addNotify(){
    super.addNotify();
    if(thread == null){
        thread = new Thread(this);
        addKeyListener(this);
        thread.start();
    }
}

public void init(){
    image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

    running = true;

    gsm = new GameStateManager();
    gsm.setState(gsm.MENUSTATE);
}

public void run(){

    init();

    long start;
    long elapsed;
    long wait;

    while(running){
        start = System.nanoTime();

        update();
        draw();
        drawToScreen();

        elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;

        wait = targetTime - elapsed / 1000000;
        if(wait < 0){
            wait = 5;
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(wait);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

private void update(){
    gsm.update();
}

private void draw(){
    gsm.draw(g);
}

private void drawToScreen(){
    Graphics g2 = getGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, (int) (WIDTH * wSCALE), (int) (HEIGHT * hSCALE), null);
    g2.dispose();
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key) {
    gsm.keyPressed(key.getKeyCode());
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent key) {
    gsm.keyReleased(key.getKeyCode());
}
}
```

It runs perfectly on my PC and there are no problems with the drawing but once I moved the files to my Macbook, it just opens a blank JFrame and does nothing. I tested to see if the methods were properly being called and they were. The draw methods are called, the keyboard input works but nothing shows up. If I set the window to be resizable, and I resize it, I can very briefly see the graphics working. I've tried a lot of solutions and none of them worked. I've looked through a lot of questions on this site and nothing seemed to work for me. Would love any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: I can not see where most of your code is getting called from? It looks like `MainWindow` should be started as a Thread

Comment: You have multiple threads without any sort of synchronization, so there's no reason than any of this has to work at all. For example, `gsm.keyPressed(...)` could legally throw `NullPointerException` because it's assigned on a different thread without synchronization/volatile. You need to read the [concurrency tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) or [just use a timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) because there is probably no particular reason to use multiple threads.

Comment: @Radiodef I'm not sure I see where I have multiple threads and even so, it seemed to cause no issues when I ran the program on my windows desktop

Comment: One thread is the Swing thread (the [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)) and the other is the thread you start in `addNotify()`. (There's also a 3rd which is the main thread.) Whether it's appeared to work on some particular system doesn't matter because it doesn't *have* to and you're asking why your code doesn't work. Realistically what will happen is you'll get an occasional NPE or your controls will seem sluggish. HotSpot might also turn your `while(running)` loop in to a `while(true)` loop. Stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use getGraphics() to do painting.

Instead, custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method of the `JPanel`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

When you want to repaint the component because a property of the panel changes then you invoke repaint() on the panel. So get rid of your update() method and simply invoke repaint() to paint the panel.

Comment: Could you address why this would cause different behavior on a mac?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils, No, because I've never used a Mac. Don't be mislead by windows working. It is just lucky and may break easily if you wake changes in the future. All I know is the proper way to do custom painting so that it will work an all platforms and you are not currently doing it.

Comment: I'm not the one asking the question but was just curious if there was more detailed/technical info.

Comment: @camickr I tried changing the code to use paintComponent() and repaint() but it did not fix the issue.